# angular2 nested routing not working,no error reported,but blank page

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, routes

Please help me check the code...There is no compilation error or else output in the cli after `npm start` .But the brower appears to be a blank page.
I have checked over and over again,but still can't find what's wrong.

PS:im a freshman in angular2...

app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AdminModule,
    WaiterModule,
    CookModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/admin",
        pathMatch:"full"
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to Angular2
  </h1>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

admin.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    DishBoardComponent,
    UserBoardComponent,
    StatisticsBoardComponent,
    AdminSiderBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

admin-routing.module

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "admin",
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "", redirectTo: "/checkout",pathMatch:"full" },
            { path: "checkout", component: CheckoutBoardComponent },
            { path: "dish", component: DishBoardComponent },
            { path: "user", component: UserBoardComponent },
            { path: "statistics", component: StatisticsBoardComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

admin.component.html

```
<p>
  admin works!
</p>
<a routerLink="/checkout">Checkout</a>
<a routerLink="/user">User</a>
<a routerLink="/dish">Dish</a>
<a routerLink="/statistics">Statistics</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<br>
footer
```

Comment: you see empty page on start itself?

Comment: @Sajeetharan empty in browser after `npm start`

Comment: whats is error in browser console?

Comment: @alexKhymenko no error in console,compiled successfully...

Comment: and no error in 'browser' console not cli console

Comment: @alexKhymenko emmmmm,'router-outlet' is not a known element:

Comment: It can be that in some component you are using <router-outlet> but you dont add RoutingModule.

Comment: @Polydick Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not defining `admin` route and its children inside your **app.routing.module**.

You should get it to work with

**app.module.ts**:

No need to import other modules here. just import `AppRoutingModule`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

/** App Modules **/
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
/** App Components**/
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.routing.module.ts**:

Load `admin.module` routes and pass them to `admin` route.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/** App Modules**/
import { AdminModule} from './admin/admin.module';

export function exportAdminModule() {
  return AdminModule;
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
         path: 'admin',
         loadChildren: exportAdminModule
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/admin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/admin'
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
  ], exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**admin.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// Import your components

/** App Routing **/
import { AdminRoutingModule} from './admin.routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // your components
        // your admin.component
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AdminRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

**admin.routing.module.ts**:

Set up an empty path as base route `''`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import your components

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: '/checkout', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutBoardComponent },
          . . .
        ]
      }
    ])
  ], exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AdminRoutingModule{ }
```

If you want to have more sub routes, for instance, nested `router-outlet` just replicate what I shown on `app.module.routing` with the export and the `loadchildren`.

I'm not quite sure that you want to achieve what you've shown on your `app.routing.module`. Are you sure you want to redirect everything to admin?

Something like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginPageComponent,
        canActivate: [PreventLoggedInAccess]
      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: exportAdminModule
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/login'
      }
    ], { useHash : true })
  ], exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

where `PreventLoggedInAccess` authguard prevents you to go to login if you are already logged in and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [
          . . .
        ]
      }
    ])
  ], exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

with `AuthGuardService` allowing accessing to child routes only if you are logged in would make much more sense in my opinion.

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/router) you can read more about authguards.